# create a single table by joining multiple tables on an assigned tablespace

Tags: oracle

I am trying to create a single table by joining 4 tables on an assigned tablespace, tbspUser1.

I used the following statement:

```
CREATE TABLE SingleTable AS(
SELECT customer.c_id AS Customer_ID, 
customer.c_uname AS CUSTOMER_UName, 
ORDERS.o_id AS Order_ID, 
ORDER_LINE.ol_i_id As Order_Item_ID, 
ITEM.I_TITLE AS Item_Title
FROM customer INNER JOIN orders ON customer.C_ID=orders.O_C_ID
INNER JOIN order_line ON orders.o_id=order_line.ol_o_id
INNER JOIN item ON order_line.ol_i_id=item.i_id) TABLESPACE tbspUser1;
```

I got the error:

```
Error starting at line 1 in command:
CREATE TABLE SingleTable AS(
SELECT customer.c_id AS Customer_ID, 
customer.c_uname AS CUSTOMER_UName, 
ORDERS.o_id AS Order_ID, 
ORDER_LINE.ol_i_id As Order_Item_ID, 
ITEM.I_TITLE AS Item_Title
FROM customer INNER JOIN orders ON customer.C_ID=orders.O_C_ID
INNER JOIN order_line ON orders.o_id=order_line.ol_o_id
INNER JOIN item ON order_line.ol_i_id=item.i_id) TABLESPACE tbspUser1
Error at Command Line:9 Column:50
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

I have been debugging and checking what is wrong with my codes, and ran my select statement on it's own:

```
SELECT customer.c_id AS Customer_ID, 
customer.c_uname AS CUSTOMER_UName, 
ORDERS.o_id AS Order_ID, 
ORDER_LINE.ol_i_id As Order_Item_ID, 
ITEM.I_TITLE AS Item_Title
FROM customer INNER JOIN orders ON customer.C_ID=orders.O_C_ID
INNER JOIN order_line ON orders.o_id=order_line.ol_o_id
INNER JOIN item ON order_line.ol_i_id=item.i_id;
```

It returned records with the following fields with no error:

```
CUSTOMER_ID CUSTOMER_UNAME         ORDER_ID ORDER_ITEM_ID ITEM_TITLE                                                 
----------- -------------------- ---------- ------------- ------------------------------------------------------------
```

I would greatly appreciate if someone could guide me on what is wrong with my create a single table by joining 4 tables on an assigned tablespace statement..

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's nothing to do with the joins. The error message point to line 9 column 50, which is the start of the keyword `TABLESPACE`, not to part of the query. Your `TABLESPACE` clause is in the wrong place:

```
CREATE TABLE SingleTable
TABLESPACE tbspUser1
AS
SELECT customer.c_id AS Customer_ID, 
customer.c_uname AS CUSTOMER_UName, 
ORDERS.o_id AS Order_ID, 
ORDER_LINE.ol_i_id As Order_Item_ID, 
ITEM.I_TITLE AS Item_Title
FROM customer INNER JOIN orders ON customer.C_ID=orders.O_C_ID
INNER JOIN order_line ON orders.o_id=order_line.ol_o_id
INNER JOIN item ON order_line.ol_i_id=item.i_id;
```

The [documentation for `create table`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_7002.htm) is quite involved, but the section for [relational tables](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_7002.htm#i2149006) shows that [physical properties](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_7002.htm#i2126711) - which includes [segment attributes](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_7002.htm#i2128666), which includes the `TABLESPACE` clause - comes before the [table properties](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_7002.htm#i2126725) - which includes the `AS subquery` clause. Which is the final part of the statement.

Creating one table that includes data from four others seems strange though; that sounds like you want a view or maybe a materialised view instead, otherwise changes to the original four tables won't be reflected in `singletable`.

Comment: Ah thanks a lot for correcting the Tablespace clause! It's working right now. :) The reason why I created the relational table as I was trying to get the smallest denormalized table to get the selected columns from the 4 tables... However, I still can't get the smallest denormalized table.. any advice? Anything that I missed out or added too much? :/

Comment: @AmAnDanG - I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Denormalising is always going to take up extra space and will be a maintenance issue (unless you have an MV). If you need those fields then I don't see how it can be smaller - not like you can get distinct values.